# Play scala - confusing about the result type of Action.async

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm little bit confusing about the expected result of Action.async. Here the use case : from the frontend, I receive a JSON to validate (a Foo), I send this data calling an another web service and I extract and validate the received JSON (Bar case class) which I want to validate too. The problem is when I return a result, I have the following error :

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Object
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
```

Here my code :

```
case class Foo(id : String)
case class Bar(id : String)

def create() = {
  Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    val sessionTokenOpt : Option[String] = request.headers.get("sessionToken")
    val sessionToken : String = "Bearer " + (sessionTokenOpt match {
      case None => throw new NoSessionTokenFound
      case Some(session) => session
    })
    val user = ""
    val structureId : Option[String] = request.headers.get("structureId")
    if (sessionToken.isEmpty) {
      Future.successful(BadRequest("no token"))
    } else {
      val url = config.getString("createURL").getOrElse("")
      request.body.validate[Foo].map {
        f =>
        Logger.debug("sessionToken = " + sessionToken)
        Logger.debug(f.toString)
        val data = Json.toJson(f)
        val holder = WS.url(url)
        val complexHolder =
          holder.withHeaders(("Content-type","application/json"),("Authorization",(sessionToken)))
        Logger.debug("url = " + url)
        Logger.debug(complexHolder.headers.toString)
        Logger.debug((Json.prettyPrint(data)))
        val futureResponse = complexHolder.put(data)
        futureResponse.map { response =>
          if(response.status == 200) {
            response.json.validate[Bar].map {
              b =>
              Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(b)))
            }.recoverTotal { e : JsError =>
              Future.successful(BadRequest("The JSON in the body is not valid."))
            }
          } else {
            Logger.debug("status from apex " + response.status)
            Future.successful(BadRequest("alo"))
          }
        }
        Await.result(futureResponse,5.seconds)
      }.recoverTotal { e : JsError =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest("The JSON in the body is not valid."))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong in my function ?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, this is doing nothing:

```
    futureResponse.map { response =>
      if(response.status == 200) {
        response.json.validate[Bar].map {
          b =>
          Future.successful(Ok(Json.toJson(b)))
        }.recoverTotal { e : JsError =>
          Future.successful(BadRequest("The JSON in the body is not valid."))
        }
      } else {
        Logger.debug("status from apex " + response.status)
        Future.successful(BadRequest("alo"))
      }
    }
```

Because you're not capturing or assigning the result of it to anything.  It's equivalent to doing this:

```
val foo = "foo"
foo + " bar"
println(foo)
```

The `foo + " bar"` statement there is pointless, it achieves nothing.

Now to debug type inference problems, what you need to do is assign results to things, and annotate with the types you're expecting.  So, assign the result of the map to something first:

```
val newFuture = futureResponse.map {
  ...
}
```

Now, what is the type of `newFuture`?  The answer is actually `Future[Future[Result]]`, because you're using `map`, and then returning a future from inside that.  If you want to return a future inside your `map` function, then you have to use `flatMap` instead, this flattens the `Future[Future[Result]]` to `Future[Result]`. But actually in your case, you don't need that you can use `map`, and just get rid of all those `Future.successful` calls, because you're not actually doing anything in that map function that needs to return a future.

And then get rid of that await as others have said - using await means blocking, which negates the point of using futures in the first place.

Anyway, this should compile:

```
def create() = {
  Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    val sessionTokenOpt : Option[String] = request.headers.get("sessionToken")
    val sessionToken : String = "Bearer " + (sessionTokenOpt match {
      case None => throw new NoSessionTokenFound
      case Some(session) => session
    })
    val user = ""
    val structureId : Option[String] = request.headers.get("structureId")
    if (sessionToken.isEmpty) {
      Future.successful(BadRequest("no token"))
    } else {
      val url = config.getString("createURL").getOrElse("")
      request.body.validate[Foo].map {
        f =>
        Logger.debug("sessionToken = " + sessionToken)
        Logger.debug(f.toString)
        val data = Json.toJson(f)
        val holder = WS.url(url)
        val complexHolder =
          holder.withHeaders(("Content-type","application/json"),("Authorization",(sessionToken)))
        Logger.debug("url = " + url)
        Logger.debug(complexHolder.headers.toString)
        Logger.debug((Json.prettyPrint(data)))
        val futureResponse = complexHolder.put(data)
        futureResponse.map { response =>
          if(response.status == 200) {
            response.json.validate[Bar].map {
              b =>
              Ok(Json.toJson(b))
            }.recoverTotal { e : JsError =>
              BadRequest("The JSON in the body is not valid.")
            }
          } else {
            Logger.debug("status from apex " + response.status)
            BadRequest("alo")
          }
        }
      }.recoverTotal { e : JsError =>
        Future.successful(BadRequest("The JSON in the body is not valid."))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Do not `Await.result(futureResponse, 5 seconds)`. Just return the `futureResponse` as is. The `Action.async` can deal with it (in fact, it wants to deal with it, it requires you to return a Future).

Note that in your various other codepaths (`else`, `recoverTotal`) you are already doing that.

Comment: Removing the await get me an another error : `type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Object]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]`. Just to be sure, from the type system, why my function (without the Await) is not well typed ?

Comment: What is the type of `futureResponse`? Maybe you have nested Futures in there, and need a bit of `flatMap`. In the end, you need to end up with `Future[Result]`.

Comment: futureResult's type : `scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse]`

Comment: you need to `map` that again to `Ok(someText)` or `BadRequest` or something.

Comment: I think you already have that `map`. But you are not using the result. Maybe return the result of the `map`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Action.async you don't need to await for result. So try to return future as is, without Await.result

Comment: Removing the await get me an another error : `type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Object]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]`.